# Magento Redis session Issue: after few hours website slows down

Tags: magento, caching, redis, magento-1.9, hhvm

I have been trying to use Redis for Magento for performance boost but I am having issues with Redis in Magneto CE 1.9.2.4.

My website after few hours slows down when I using Redis, sometimes it can took about one minute to load a page. Strange that admin zone works normaly.

I'm using easyengine stack to install main dependencies to server: hhvm as a php compiler, nginx as a webserver, redis as a cache server.

Server OS: Ubuntu 14.04
CPU: 4 x 2.40 GHz
RAM:    3072 MB + 384 MB plus + 1536 MB SWAP (using 3261 MB)

[server ram usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwVKJ.png)

My local.xml config:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Wed, 27 Apr 2016 21:17:58 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[***********]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[*********]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[*********]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[*********]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>

    <!-- redis cache -->
        <cache>
          <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
          <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server>                               
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent></persistent>                                
            <database>0</database>                                   
            <password></password>                                   
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>                   
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>                     
            <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>                          
            <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> 
            <compress_data>1</compress_data>                         
            <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>                         
            <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>           
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>                  
            <use_lua>0</use_lua>                                     
          </backend_options>
        </cache>

    <!-- redis session storage -->
        <session_save>db</session_save>
        <redis_session>                                          
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>                               
            <port>6379</port>
            <password></password>                                
            <timeout>2.5</timeout>                               
            <persistent></persistent>                            
            <db>1</db>                                           
            <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>  
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>              
            <log_level>1</log_level>                             
            <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>                 
            <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>       
            <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
            <first_lifetime>600</first_lifetime>                 
            <bot_first_lifetime>60</bot_first_lifetime>          
            <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>                    
            <disable_locking>0</disable_locking>                 
            <min_lifetime>60</min_lifetime>                      
            <max_lifetime>2592000</max_lifetime>                 
        </redis_session>
    </global>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

HHVM php.ini config:

```
; php options
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = /var/lib/hhvm/sessions
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

; hhvm specific 
hhvm.log.level = Warning
hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 8191
hhvm.mysql.typed_results = false
hhvm.log.header = true
hhvm.log.natives_stack_trace = true
hhvm.mysql.socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
hhvm.pdo_mysql.socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
hhvm.mysqli.socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
hhvm.log.header = true
hhvm.log.natives_stack_trace = true
```

mysql config:

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
skip-external-locking

max_connections     = 100
connect_timeout     = 5
wait_timeout        = 600
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_cache_size       = 128
sort_buffer_size    = 4M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size      = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M

myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
key_buffer_size     = 128M
#open-files-limit   = 2000
table_open_cache    = 400
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 512M
concurrent_insert   = 2
read_buffer_size    = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 1M

query_cache_limit       = 128K
query_cache_size        = 64M

log_warnings        = 2

slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time = 10
log_slow_verbosity  = query_plan

log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index       = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index

expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

default_storage_engine  = InnoDB

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files   = 400
innodb_io_capacity  = 400
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Answer (score 0):

**Redis session locking**

***STEP 1:***

Add `<disable_locking>` to your Magento local.xml

```
<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
<redis_session>
.
.
   <disable_locking>1</disable_locking>
</redis_session>
```

***STEP 2:***

NB: Older versions of Cm_RedisSession do not have this feature.
To find out, open up app/code/community/Cm/RedisSession/Model/Session.php and look for “disable_locking”.

grep disable_locking app/code/community/Cm/RedisSession -r
app/code/community/Cm/RedisSession/Model/Session.php:                    : ! (strlen("{$config->descend('disable_locking')}") ? (bool)"{$config->descend('disable_locking')}" : self::DEFAULT_DISABLE_LOCKING);

```
If you see the above, it will work with no further action. This updated code is bundled as of Magento CE 1.9 or EE 1.14.
If you don’t see that, then the module needs to be updated.
```

Comment: Hi Rebin, thank you for respond. May I ask, what exactly disable locking do?